# Calculate distance between data points and centroid (kmeans) using sklearn in python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, k-means

I am trying to do clustering using kmeans by sklearn. I need to compute the distance between each data point and its centroid. Can anyone help me here.

Thanks in advance

```
import re
import sys
import os
import sklearn.datasets
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
dataFilename = sys.argv[1]
X, y = sklearn.datasets.load_svmlight_file(dataFilename)
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=3)
kmeans.fit(X)
centroids = kmeans.cluster_centers_
labels = kmeans.predict(X)
j=0
intervals = []
for i in range(0,max(labels)+1):
    intervals.append([])
print(intervals)
for i in y:
    intervals[labels[j]].append(int(y[j]))
    j += 1
print(intervals)
```

Comment: Hi @Mohammed, can you add what you've tried to do, what you is exactly, etc? It's hard to answer with just a block of code and a description of what you want it to do.

Comment: I am trying to do clustering using kmeans through sklearn in python. I have a data file in LIBSVM format
The format of training and testing data file is:
<label> <index1>:<value1> <index2>:<value2> ...
I need to sort the data points in each cluster in ascending order based on the difference between each data point and its centroid,

Comment: Yes, but what have you already tried? What errors are you encountering? What does your current code do/ not do? Review the how to ask guide (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more details.